# Snowflake - Execute the output of a query in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query (`foreign_keys.sql`) that creates foreign keys, the output are rows of ALTER statements to add FK's but how can I execute these statements?

example row:

```
ALTER TABLE "EIV"."RTR"."LINEITEMS" 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ITEM_ID) REFERENCES "EIV"."RTR"."ID_LINEITEMS" (ID);
```

Below if how I would run this in Airflow, but then how do I then execute the statements?

```
snp_create_foreign_keys = SnowflakeQueryOperator(
        task_id='create_foreign_keys',
        sql='queries/foreign_keys.sql',
        params={
            'schema': 'qtr'
        },
        retries=0)
```

This is what our SnowflakeQueryOperator looks like:

```
class SnowflakeQueryOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_fields = ['sql', 'params']
    template_ext = ['.sql']

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                 sql,
                 params=None,
                 warehouse=Variable.get('default_snowflake_warehouse'),
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.sql = sql
        self.params = params
        self.warehouse = warehouse

    def execute(self, context):
        sf_hook = SnowflakeHook(warehouse=self.warehouse)

        self.log.info(f'Running query:')

        sf_hook.execute_query(self.sql)
```

Comment: what do you mean , your code supposed to run the sql file, whatever command is in it , you havn;t shown but you need a snowflake connection to your snowflake in airflow

Comment: @eshirvana I've updated to show what our SnowflakeQueryOperator looks like, I'm wondering how in the query I could also not just run the query (/foreign_keys.sql) that populates the rows with the alter statements, but how to also loop through each row and execute?

Comment: each row in the file you mean? it will run everything in the file line by line .

Comment: @eshirvana The file only has 1 query statement, the output of that statement are several rows of "alter table,... etc", I want to read and execute each output row

Comment: It walk run all the code inside that file, why you wanna. Run them one by one ?

Comment: @eshirvana the query in the file is 1 query, the output of that 1 query is 75 rows of 'alter table, etc' that I want to be able to run, I just need all of those rows to be run, all of those alter table statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the SnowflakeOperator in Airflow doesn't return the results of a select query, it should only be used to execute queries on Snowflake (like most database operators) and either fail or succeed.

You would need to write your own operator to do this.